# Find input elementID of the input field that the user has selected

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I have a `UIWebView` and have loaded a document from a server. The web document has several text input fields. How do I determine the ID or name of the field that the user has touched - selected. I would then like to assign a value to populate the input field.

I have read enough to believe I need JavaScript but do not know how to associate it with objective c in Xcode. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks
Ron

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Tasks/ObjCFromJavaScript.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, but that was just part of my question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example of a simple implementation that can get you started.

### example.html

```
<script type="text/javacript">
    function populateField(fieldId, fieldText) {
        $('#' + fieldId).val(fieldText);
    }

    var bridgeScheme = 'myapp';
    (function($) {
        $('#my-textfield').on('focus', function() {
            var data = {
                'action': 'focus',
                'field-id': $(this).attr('id')
            };
            var encodedData = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data));

            $('#iframe').attr('src', bridgeScheme + encodedData);
        });
    })(jQuery)
</script>

<form id="my-form">
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="my-textfield">
    </div>
</form>

<iframe src="" id="iframe"></iframe>
```

A few things:

- The `iframe` is used to generate a request which will go through the
  `UIWebView`. We will be able to capture it by implementing
  `UIWebViewDelegate` in the controller (see after)
- The `bridgeScheme` variable is how you'll be able to detect that a request is coming from your own javascript code (see after)
- The `populateField` javascript function will be called from the native side to populate the text field with whatever value you want

---

### ExampleViewController.m

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
  // This needs to be the same value as used in the javascript
  NSString *bridgeScheme = @"myapp";

  // That's where we capture the request if the request's scheme matches
  if ([request.URL.scheme isEqualToString:bridgeScheme])
  {
    // Extract the part of the request url that contains the data we need
    NSString *dataString = [request.URL.absoluteString substringFromIndex:bridgeScheme.length + 1];
    // The data was URL encoded
    dataString = [dataString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    // Here we transform the JSON string into a JSON object (dictionary)
    NSData *data = [dataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

    // Extract the field id from the dictionary
    NSString *fieldId = dataDictionary[@"field-id"];

    // Call the javascript method on the webview
    NSString *populateFieldJS = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"populateField('%@', '%@')", fieldId, @"Whatever text you want to put in there"];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:populateFieldJS];

    return NO;
  }

  return YES;
}
```

Hope it helps!